# How can I operate date variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I got the following variables:

```
today = new Date();
date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();

console.log(date)

------
Output
------
2021-9-6
```

How can I get the date from yesterday or 2 day ago?
I tried:

```
console.log(today-2)
console.log(date-2)
------
Output
------
1630936602270
NaN
```

I expected the follwing output `2021-9-4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let twoDaysAgoInMs =2*24*3600*1000;
console.log(new Date((new Date()).getTime()- twoDaysAgoInMs))


 // to get only YYYY-mm-dd
 console.log(new Date((new Date()).getTime()- twoDaysAgoInMs).toISOString().substring(0,10))
```